# Inserts into Sybase table in the cursor fetch loop

Tags: t-sql, sybase, sap-ase

I am writing a Sybase stored procedure with a cursor fetching records from table and inserting records back. Surprisingly I found that fetches see amd return records inserted in the same loop. Under some conditions this results in endless loop, sometimes the loop ends inseting a number of extra records. Looking through Sybase documentation I could not find a cure. Transaction isolation does not help since we are acting inside a single transaction. Of course I could solve the problem by inserting into a temporary table in the loop and then inserting back into main table after the loop ends.
But the question remain: **how can I isolate cursor fetches from inserts into the same table**?
Pseudocode follows:

```
create table t (v int)
go
insert into t(v) values (1)
create procedure p as
begin
 declare @v int
 declare c cursor for select v from t
 begin transaction
 open c
 while 1=1 begin
  fetch c into @v
  if (@@sqlstatus != 0) break
  insert into t (v) values (@v+1)
 end
 close c
 commit
end
go
exec p
go
```

Comment: Which Sybase product are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I was surprised by this behavior, too. Cursors only iterate over rows, they are not immune to changes during the loop. The [manual](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32300.1600/doc/html/san1390612481758.html) states this:

> A searched or positioned update on an allpages-locked table can change
>   the location of the row; for example, if it updates key columns of a
>   clustered index. The cursor does not track the row; it remains
>   positioned just before the next row at the original location.
>   Positioned updates are not allowed until a subsequent fetch returns
>   the next row. The updated row may be visible to the cursor a second
>   time, if the row moves to a later position in the search order

My solution was to insert into a temporary table and copy the results back at the end, this also sped up the process by a factor of about 10.

Pseudo-code:

```
select * into #results from OriginalTable where 1<>1 --< create temp table with same columns
WHILE fetch...
BEGIN
      insert into #results
      select -your-results-here
END
insert into OriginalTable select * from #results
```